# MacOSがSierraでiOS実機ビルドでlocalhostのサーバにアクセスするには？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

MacOSをSierraにしてからlocalhostでたてたサーバーに実機でアクセスできなくなってしまいました。
以前まではシステム環境設定 > 共有に書かれているアドレスを取得してアクセスすることで実機ビルドに成功していました。

どのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか？
教えていただけると大変助かります。

Comment: **Apache**という言葉はご存知ですか？macOSで、ウェブサーバを立てるというのは、このApacheを起動することに他なりません。運用の仕方は、UNIX/Linuxと同じなので、ネット検索すれば、いくつも情報がヒットします。なお、SierraでApacheを制御するコマンド`apachectl`は、/usr/sbinにあります。

Comment: @nagonsoftware 
ブラウザ上でアクセスできるのでサーバは起動できている状態でした。

そして、申し訳ないのですが、iOSアプリがhttpsしか許可しないという設定になっており、そのせいでアクセスできないというのが原因でした。
共有に書かれているアドレスは例外的に許可してあげれば大丈夫でした。

お忙しいところご回答いただきありがとうございました。